# How to use a pointer to array of string without cast

Tags: pointers, pascal, lazarus

Options 1 and 2 are working fine but I don't like using "TArrayString()", I'd rather use something like option 3 (which is not working).

```
program project1;
type TArrayString = array of string;

const
   n_signals = 3;
var
   signals_1    : array [1..n_signals] of string = ('101', '102', '103');
   i            :integer;
   ptr_signals  : pointer;
   ptr_signals2 : ^TArrayString;
begin

  ptr_signals  := @signals_1;
  ptr_signals2 := @signals_1;

  WriteLn('1) Void Pointer + Cast:');
  for i:=0 to n_signals-1 do begin
    writeLn('senal' + TArrayString(ptr_signals)[i]);
  end;
  WriteLn('');

  WriteLn('2) TArrayString Pointer + Cast:');
  for i:=0 to n_signals-1 do begin
    writeLn('senal' + TArrayString(ptr_signals2)[i]);
  end;
  WriteLn('');

  WriteLn('3) TArrayString Pointer + NO Cast: => Not working!!');
  for i:=0 to n_signals-1 do begin
    writeLn('senal' + ptr_signals2^[i]); // ¿¿??
  end;
  WriteLn('');
```

Output look like this:

```
1) Void Pointer + Cast:
senal101
senal102
senal103

2) TArrayString Pointer + Cast:
senal101
senal102
senal103

3) TArrayString Pointer + NO Cast: => Not working!!
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Dynamic array and fixed length array aren't the same thing. Your first two work, but by accident. They aren't correct. The third option doesn't work because dynamic array variable is a pointer to the array and so ptr_signals2 holds a double pointer but you assign a single pointer. And you have not enabled typed addresses so in effect you have a cast and the compiler can't save you. What I don't know is what your goal is so I can't advise on how best to achieve that goal.

Comment: 1) I have many "signals" arrays and I have to do each time the same process over just one of the arrays therefore, It would be nice to be able to use the same code and select an array each time. 2) Which is the correct way of boing the first two way so that they work (but not by accident). Thank you.

Comment: And "signals" arrays are global variables so passing them to a function by ref doesn't seem like the best option.

Comment: Probably the right way you talk about is this one: 
parray: array[1..MAX] of ^string; 
for i := 1 to MAX do parray[i] := @names[i];
But I don't like it because it is too long.

Comment: It depends on whether the array size is known at compile time, and probably some other considerations.

Comment: they are static arrays so you know dimensions at compile time, but they all have different sizes.

Comment: So pass a pointer to the first element of the array and do POINTERMATH ON or whatever the fpc equivalent is

Comment: From wikipedia: "Pointer arithmetic is enabled in FPC/OBJFPC modes and disabled in DELPHI mode", so it looks like first two were not working by accident. Thanks.

Comment: No they were working by accident. That cast to dynamic array is wrong because the structure that you cast isn't a dynamic array.

Comment: No, dyn array of integer would also be array of values. What's different is that a dyn array has meta data, the ref count and the array length.

Comment: First: sorry for my ignorance. I think you are right and they are different (one static and the other dynamic), but as far as we talk about an array of string both structures contains an array of pointers and are the same. It would be different if they were arrays of integers, the static one would have an array of values while the dynamic one would have an array of pointers.  Could you modify the array contents in any way to make the code fail?

Comment: Sorry @David Heffernan I was editing my comment while you were answering... :) Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @David Heffernan I have written an answer based on your explanatios (see below). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @David Hefferman answers and in [this post](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#dynarrays) I have done this code update, I am not sure if it is the right answer but atleast is one possible option.

Seems like:

- A dynamic arrays pointer (^TArrayString) pointing to a static array (signals) do the job but not in right way.
- Using a static array pointer (^TArrayStringStatic) to a static array (signals) do job in the right way and there is no need to Cast (point 5).

Program:

```
program project1;
type TArrayString = array of string;
type TArrayStringStatic = array [0..65535] of string;

const
   n_signals = 3;
var
   signals      : array [1..n_signals] of string = ('10199999999', '102', '103777777');
   i            :integer;
   ptr_signals_void : pointer;
   ptr_signals_dyn  : ^TArrayString;
   ptr_signals_stat : ^TArrayStringStatic;
begin

  ptr_signals_void  := @signals;
  ptr_signals_dyn   := @signals;
  ptr_signals_stat  := @signals;

  WriteLn('1) Void Pointer + Cast (Dynamic Array):');
  for i:=0 to n_signals-1 do begin
    writeLn('senal' + TArrayString(ptr_signals_void)[i]);
  end;
  WriteLn('');

  WriteLn('2) TArrayString Pointer + Cast (Dynamic Array):');
  for i:=0 to n_signals-1 do begin
    writeLn('senal' + TArrayString(ptr_signals_dyn)[i]);
  end;
  WriteLn('');

  WriteLn('3) TArrayString Pointer + NO Cast: => Not working!!');
  for i:=0 to n_signals-1 do begin
    //writeLn('senal' + ptr_signals_dyn^[i]);          // ¿¿why not??
    //writeLn('senal' + string(ptr_signals_dyn[i]));   // Works
  end;
  WriteLn('');

  WriteLn('4) TArrayStringStatic Pointer + Cast (Static Array):');
  for i:=0 to n_signals-1 do begin
    writeLn('senal' + TArrayStringStatic(ptr_signals_stat^)[i]);
  end;
  WriteLn('');

  WriteLn('5) TArrayStringStatic Pointer + No Cast:');
  for i:=0 to n_signals-1 do begin
    writeLn('senal' + ptr_signals_stat^[i]);
  end;
  WriteLn('');

end.
```

Output:

```
1) Void Pointer + Cast (Dynamic Array):
senal10199999999
senal102
senal103777777

2) TArrayString Pointer + Cast (Dynamic Array):
senal10199999999
senal102
senal103777777

3) TArrayString Pointer + NO Cast: => Not working!!

4) TArrayStringStatic Pointer + Cast (Static Array):
senal10199999999
senal102
senal103777777

5) TArrayStringStatic Pointer + No Cast:
senal10199999999
senal102
senal103777777
```

Thank you.